# Validate specific fields of a single form for various select box changes - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have an input form with 4 fields. Frequency(text box), Ad Size(text box), Input 1(select box), Input 2(select box). I am using Query validation.

How to validate specific fields of a single form for various select box changes.
1. Validate frequency field during ip1 onchange
2. Validate adsize field during ip2 onchange

**A sample code**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

$("#ip1").change(function() {
$('#simpleform').valid()});
})

$("#ip2").change(function() {
$('#simpleform').valid()});
})

$("#simpleform").validate({ //use this during ip1 change
  rules: {
    frequency: "required"
  },
  messages: {
    frequency: "Please specify your frequency"
  }
});

$("#simpleform").validate({ //use this during ip2 change
  rules: {
    adsize: "required"
  },
  messages: {
    adsize: "Please specify adsize"
  }
});


</script>
<body>

<form id="simpleform">
Frequency : <input type="text" name="frequency"><br>
Ad Size: <input type="text" name="adsize"><br>
Input 1: 
<select id="ip1">
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
</select>
<br>
Input 2: 
<select id="ip2">
<option>X</option>
<option>Y</option>
<option>Z</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain what kind of validation you want to do? just saying `How to validate specific fields of a single form for various select box changes.` is not enough, can you explain with an example

Comment: You can use `depends` for conditioning validation based on selected option. Refer this - http://jsfiddle.net/mvandiest/hJGsU/

Answer (score 2):

You Can Try This for Select Value Validations:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("select").change(function(){
         var select_value = jQuery(this).val();
         if(select_value == "")
         {
             jQuery(this).next("span.err_msg:first").text("Please Select Value").show();
             return false;
         }
         else
         {
             jQuery(this).next("span.err_msg:first").hide();
         }
    });
});
```

Add In HTML

```
<select id="ip1">
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
</select>
<span class="err_msg"><span>
```